# Block a JDialog when I open another one

Tags: java, swing, block, jdialog

I've got a JDialog with a button that opens a new window. What I want to do is to block this JDialog whenever the other window opens. When I say block I mean that the user cannot manipulate it, not move it or maximisize or anything.

By the way, is it recommended to use JDialog for a window with buttons and a table? I stil don't get it when I have to use which frame!

This is what I've got:

```
public class Platos extends JDialog {

    private final JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Platos dialog = new Platos();
            dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }    

    public Platos() {
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        contentPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        contentPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        getContentPane().add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        {
            JButton btnAgregarPlato = new JButton("Agregar Plato");
            btnAgregarPlato.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                AgregarPlato ap = new AgregarPlato();
                ap.setVisible(true);
                }
            });
            btnAgregarPlato.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11));
            contentPanel.add(btnAgregarPlato);
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

JDialog is the right choice indeed.

To make it block the parent window, you would have to add a constructor to Platos, which will utilise the `JDialog` constructor with *parent* frame:

```
JDialog dlg = new JDialog(parentWindow, modality);
```

Where `parentWindow` is typically a JFrame.

You do it like this:

```
public Platos(JFrame parent) {
    super(parent, ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    ....
```

The trick is the `ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL` argument, which makes your dialog block all other dialogs *and* the main frame.

You can pass as parent the main window, it will work just fine even if you are opening the dialog from another one - the last one blocks all the previous ones.

---

For more reference, see the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html).